# How do I train model in Google NLP Sentiment Analysis correctly

Tags: google-app-engine, sentiment-analysis, nlp

I need to compare to sentiment models trained with different types of content. Google supplies you with a training dataset filled with tweets in a .csv file, As expected training with this went well however, when I decided to train a model using the Stanford NLP's dataset of IMDB reviews, I manage to upload the dataset without issue but when I train it the NLP, for some reason only predicts that the sentiment value is 2, regardless of what I write.

I figured that the dataset was diluted since, while there were 800-2000 examples of sentiment 0,1,3 and 4, there were 6000 examples of sentiment 2. Although after removing 4000 of these examples, the problem persisted.

I'm expecting my confusion matrix to not simply only have 100% prediction on each sentiment value. It should be distributed over the matrix w

Comment: I think you would get much better answers on datascience.stackexchange.com

Comment: I know this is a bit old. but however: Having an uneven distribution is typical for sentiment analysis and is something your model should be able to deal with. So stratified sampling is important instead of evening your bins. If your only prediction is '2' your model does not fit the problem/context and is not applicable to the different context (maybe the data differs too much). Generally, in case of uneven distributions you should much more rely on precision/recall/f1 instead of accuracy (you did not write about acc, but I wanted to mention).